# Generate one hash with size 12 from String

Tags: java, hash

Is it possible to generate one hash with 12 character (letter and numbers) from string? just like a md5 but with only 12 chars?

Using Java.

tks

Comment: what did you try till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a hash code from every object in Java (which is almost everything).

So you can use the `hashCode()` method to obtain the hash from the String. There is no way to set the length of the hash you'll obtain, but you can always parse the hash to a String and truncate it with a substring.

This way, you could do something like this:

```
//Get the hash
int hash = yourString.hashCode();
//Parse it to String
String yourHash = Integer.toString(hash);
//Truncate the hash
String truncatedHash = yourHash.substring(0, 12)
```

If you want your hash back to an integer, you just have to do `Integer.parseInt(truncatedHash)`.

This is not the clearest solution, but I don't know what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Nice but I forgot to tell, that hash should be one ID, so I need garantee that wont be duplicate sometime.

Comment: @Fabio, that's literally impossible.  If you took all the strings of length 13, and put them into whatever algorithm you choose, you will have to get some duplicates, because there's more possible strings of length 13 than there are strings of length 12.

Comment: If you want a key or something to identify your Strings, the easiest way to do that is just taking the hash code from the object, without truncating it to just 12 characters.